# if statement incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I want to have the variable estimatedVal replaced with avgList if estimatedVal is empty. Something is wrong with my code because with the code below nothing happens. If I remove the if statement everything else works:

```
$('#estimatedVal').html($(context).find('ul.estimates a:eq(1)').text()
                                + ' - ' + $(context).find('ul.estimates a:eq(0)').text());


if(estimatedVal == ' - '") {
$('#estimatedVal').html(avgList);
} else {
$('#estimatedVal').html(estimatedVal);
}
```

What do I need to do to be able to use the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a "lonely double quote," use an IDE/Code Editor and quit using Notepad :P

```
if(estimatedVal == ' - ') {
    $('#estimatedVal').html(avgList);
} else {
    $('#estimatedVal').html(estimatedVal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a stray double quote in your if.